# Send dynamic zip files using nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, zip, attachment

I have a group of attachments which are to be zipped by js and the zip file should be sent to the user as an attachment.

I am trying to zip the file using archiver.

If I add this zip files to the array of attachments in node mailer the file is corrupted since path is required for node mailer.

Any other way to dynamically create zip files without saving a copy on local or on server which can be reused to send to the client

```
var zip = Archiver('zip');
  zip.append(file_to_be_zipped, { name: 'file2.txt' })
.finalize();

from: configuration.data.from,
to: req.body.to.join(';'),
cc: req.body.cc && req.body.cc.join(';'),
bcc: req.body.bcc && req.body.bcc.join(';'),
subject: subject,
html: body,
attachments: zip
```

Comment: Archiver creates a stream, that should be able to be [attached](https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/) as the above answer/docco describes

Comment: I tried attaching the file but the format is not the zip file the attachment is some non readable file that's getting passed. If we pass a path with the zip file then its working but how to pass a path if the file is dynamic?

Comment: specify a `filename` that you want the attachment to appear as, and the `content:` is the zip stream from Archiver ?

Comment: for text files its working of i have to stream a pdf file the data is not in readable format